# Image upload issue using Nodejs Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, upload

I am new in Nodejs and working on express,Right now i am trying to upload image but i am facing two issues

```
1) Image format/extension is wrong , showing "file" instead of original image (.jpg or png or other extension should be added) 
2) If we pass "file","image" or other parameters then 2 or more files uploading,There should be one parameter "image"
```

Here is my current code

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/'});
var fs = require('fs');
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});

 var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any('userPhoto');
 const uploadavatar = function (req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file." + err);
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below code for filename function

```js
filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        const originalname = file.originalname;
        const fileExt = originalname.split(".").pop();
        const excatName = originalname.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".");
        callback(null, excatName + "-" + Date.now().toString() + "." + fileExt);
      },
```

Comment: your code is working fine but what about 2nd point , means if i pass any extra parameters (type =file) then multiple images uploading , i want to use only 1 parameter (image) for this api

Comment: where you are using this parameter in the code? Show full code here